# How to properly launch an activity without keep calling onResume when Activity in is in foreground?

Tags: android, android-intent

Ok I have an automatic flow to call an activity:

> - When user goes to another application from my application after some interval time.
> - Even the application is in foreground, I still call the same flow to call this code again.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

This flag going to call OnResume for second scenario.

Comment: can you tell more clearance about your expected output?

Comment: If activity is in foreground, after I call the intent, OnResume must not be called again.

Comment: we can't stop android life cycle it should be called onResume.But inside onResume we can stop your invoke methods.

Comment: You can't skip an Activity's lifecycle so easily. You should instead change your code to achieve what you want. Hint: use boolean flags

Comment: There is no way to skip that part, that's the natural way of calling android life cycle methods. It's not recommended to do anything that can harm the flow because it can cause a lot problems and memory leaks.